# how to add custom security policy and referrer policy on nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, nginx-ingress

i just try with configuration-snippet anotation but didn't work

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'";
  more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: 'same-origin';"
  more_set_headers "Feature-Policy: "geolocation 'none'; vibrate 'none';";"
```

is any other way?
my nginx controller version is nginx-ingress:1.8.1 and running on gcp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nginx Ingress Controller** has its own way of defining [custom http headers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-headers/) for upstream server.

You're trying to use a method which requires installation of the additional thrid-party module for **nginx**. This module is not packed into the [base image of the **Controller**](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/images/nginx).